# deserialize JSON object receive via REST API (c# web api 2)

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm sending an JSON Object to a rest server using a WebRequest.
The ContentType is set to application/json

The original class is serialized to JSON string, than the string in converted to byte (using BlockCopy than makes it a unicode) and sent via HTTP.

On the server side I revieve a a JContainer Object rather than the string (probably b/c of the Content Type)

How do I Deserialize this object directly with JSON.NET ?

I was able to turn this to a string and then deserialize it, but with some errors that I can't trace as the string is unreadable (lots of \0 from the unicode conversion....)

My question is - can I deserialize the original JSON Object ? 
Is there a way to convert this object to a regular ASCII string ?

```
public void Put(MyClass cls)
{
}

// I get nothing

public void Put(JContainer cls)
{
    string myjson = cls.ToString()
** Update: This string is the original JSON but in UNICODE.
** this text doesn't deserialized to the original class.

}
```

Comment: What you get if you write this line - `dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`

Comment: DeserializeObject wants a string. I get an object which I found to be JContainter Object.

Comment: When you say "I revieve a JContainer Object rather than the string", what do you mean exactly? Is this a parameter in your endpoint? If so, what type is it in the code? If it's an object than json.net probably deserialized for you into a generic object, which means you can just use the desired object as a parameter type and things should be taken care of.

Comment: Even better - post your web method's code so we can understand what you already tried.

Comment: Automatic conversion doesn't work (maybe because it's a nested class which is beyond the auto-converter scope), so if I use the actual class as parameter I get null in all properties.

Comment: I think the real issue is converting the JContainter Object to a full json string (and not only the top level objects...)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, because JContainer IS a deserialization of the actual json you got. Could you sniff the request that is made to the server and show us how the class and the json looks?
Also, nested classes shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You are correct. It's the whole string, but I think the unicode messes it up. I deserialized the original string and it worked ok. The JContainer string representation will not deserilaized, and the JContainer object will not cast to my own class...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60809/discussion-between-mot-and-dani).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the encoding. 
using ASCII encoding instead of Unicode solved all De-Serialization problems.
Just Took the JContainer.ToString() and sent it to the Deserialize function.

Comment: This sounds suspicious. Are you sure non-ASCII characters didn't get lost in this process?

Comment: In this case you can just ask for the actual class you are deserializing to as a parameter. JContainer is a deserialization of the original json

Comment: It works as you describe it, but only if I send the JSON encoded as ASCII. Once it goes unicode, the deserialization fails.